# LocalDB, table definition with comments

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, localdb

I am using Visual Studio ...if I am creating a LocalDb with the framework, everything is fine. After creating or updating an table with a comment on an column and opening table definition ...The comments I created are gone away!?

Creating:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Filter] (
    [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    -- some very usefull hint
    [Name]        NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    -- some important hint
    [Description] NVARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
    -- some very usefull hint
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Updating:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Filter] (
    [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]        NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (512) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Is it not possible to add some comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database does not store comments in its schema definitions.
All you can do is store and or check in your table definition SQL script (with our without comments) along with other files of your Visual Studio project if you like to.